# Silent push notification (APNS) can not received

Tags: ios, silent-notification

I have set up the silent push notification for my app:
1. I configured the push notification from all places, i.e., XCode, Apple Developer portal with proper certificate
2. I enabled background capability
3. I included "content-available" in the json payload.

However, my App can not receive silent push sometimes.

To be more specific, neither

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    ......
}
```

nor

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_: UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    ......
}
```

has been invoked when the push message arrives.

How can I get the information in the push notification in such state?

I'm waiting online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is twofold:
1. why the two delegate callbacks can not be invoked
2. what should you do to receive the data.

I did some hand test and here is the result:

1, when an app is in killed state, the two callback can not be invoked indeed
2. however, when you open the app next time,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ......
}
```

can be invoked and you can get the data from there.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: I am not receiving such silent push notifications even when the app is in the foreground state. Any catch?